# Identify if there is text present in a text fields with class="x"

Tags: jquery

I have three `text box's` that a user can enter text into but I don't know what there going to enter. I want to see if there is text in the box's. I know I can use jQuery to find out if there is text if I know the text entry

```
$( ".x:contains('John')" )
```

but I don't know what they are going to enter so is there a fix for this?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly what you have now will not work because `:contains` looks for text within the `text()` property of the element or its children.

If you just want to check if the field has a value you can do this:

```
if ($('.x').val()) {
   // this field has a value
}
```

If you want to check is has a value which contains the word `John` you can do this:

```
if ($('.x').val().contains('John')) {
   // this field has a value, and it contains the word John
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to know if the text boxes are filled up with something (no matter what), that's a way:

```
if ($(".x").val())
    // Non empty text box
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$('.x').val().length` to get the length of a textfield/textarea.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$('.x').val()` to get the value

Comment: aye I know I could do that but I want to know if there is text in more that one of them! so I can use if (textboxesactive>1){}

Answer (score 0):

As you used a class instead of an id for the selector: If those are multiple fields and you want to find all with or without a value use:

```
// get all fields with a value
var fields = $('.x').filter(function() { return ('' != $(this).val()); });

// get all fields without a value
var fields = $('.x').filter(function() { return ('' == $(this).val()); });
```

Use [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) if those are form input fields. Use [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) if those are any other type of container, like a `<div>` for example.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to check if the field as value or noy just do this:

```
if($(".x").val()!=null && $(".x").val()!=""){
   //this field as value
}
```

If there are multiple fields with same class `.x` you can use `.each` and check:

```
$(".x").each(function(){
    if($(this).val()!=null && $(this).val()!=""){
       //this field as value
    }
}
```